# 404 error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I get this error soon after I login.

> Not Found
>   
> The requested URL /beat/home/userhome was not found on this server.

Controller - home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');class Home extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    /*$CURRENT_URL='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $CURRENT_URL=str_replace("/index.php", "", $CURRENT_URL);
    if($this->session->userdata('CURRENT_URL')){
        if($this->session->userdata('CURRENT_URL')!=$CURRENT_URL){
            $this->session->set_userdata('CURRENT_URL', $CURRENT_URL);
        } else {
            redirect($this->session->userdata('CURRENT_URL'), 'refresh');
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->set_userdata('CURRENT_URL', $CURRENT_URL);
    }
    */
    $this->load->model('log_model');
    $this->log_model->update();
    $pageData=array('formError'=>'');
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userid', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
           $this->load->model('user_model');
           if($this->user_model->check_login()){
             $this->log_model->updatelogin();
             redirect('home/userhome', 'refresh');
           } else {
              $pageData=array('formError'=>'Invalid username/password.');
              $this->load->view('index', $pageData);
           }
        } else {
           $this->load->view('index', $pageData);
        }
    } else {
      $this->load->view('index', $pageData);
    }
}

function changepassword(){
    if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}

    $pageData=array();
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $pageData['status']=$this->user_model->changepassword();
    }
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('changepassword', $pageData);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

function test(){
    /*$this->load->model('client_db_model');
    $cdb=$this->client_db_model->connect(104);
    $res=$cdb->query('CALL msp()');
    print_r($res->result());*/
    $this->load->view('advtable');
}

function logout(){
    $this->session->unset_userdata('company_id');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_name');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('CURRENT_URL');
    $this->load->model('log_model');
    $this->log_model->updatelogout();
    //$_SESSION['CURRENT_URL']=base_url();
    redirect('./', 'refresh');
}

function checklogin(){
    return ($this->session->userdata('company_id')*1>0)?true:false;
}

public function userhome(){
  if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
  $this->checkmaintenance();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $pageData['lentmenu']='userhome';
  $pageData['dashboards']=$this->user_model->getdashboards();
  $this->load->view('header', $pageData);
  $this->load->view('userhome');
  $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function uploadfiles(){
  //$this->session->set_userdata(array('company_id'=>0));
  if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
  $this->checkmaintenance();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $pageData['lentmenu']='uploadfiles';
  $pageData['dashboards']=$this->user_model->getdashboards();
  $this->load->view('header', $pageData);
  $this->load->view('uploadfiles');
  $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function dashboard($dashboard_id=NULL){
  if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
  $this->checkmaintenance();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $pageData['lentmenu']='dashboard';
  $_SESSION['dashboard_id']=$dashboard_id;
  /*$pageData['dashboards']=$this->user_model->getdashboards();
  $pageData['smallboxes']=$this->user_model->getsmallboxes($dashboard_id);*/
  $pageData['comments']=$this->user_model->getcomments($dashboard_id);
  $pageData['dashboard_id']=$dashboard_id;
  $this->load->view('header', $pageData);
  $this->load->view('dashboard');
  $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function getchart($dashboardwidget_id){
  if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
  $this->checkmaintenance();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $rtnVar=$this->user_model->getchart($dashboardwidget_id);
  echo json_encode($rtnVar);
}

public function postcomment(){
  if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
   //$this->checkmaintenance();
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $rtnVar=$this->user_model->postcomment();
   echo json_encode($rtnVar);
}

public function createpdf(){
  if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
    $this->load->helper('pdf_helper');
    /*
        ---- ---- ---- ----
        your code here
        ---- ---- ---- ----
    */
    $this->load->view('pdfreport');
}

function pdf($dashboard_id)
{
  if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
     $this->load->model('user_model');
     $pageData['lentmenu']='dashboard';
     $pageData['dashboards']=$this->user_model->getdashboards();
     $pageData['comments']=$this->user_model->getcomments($dashboard_id);
     $pageData['dashboard_id']=$dashboard_id;
     $html=$this->load->view('dashboard');
     $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
     // page info here, db calls, etc.     
     //$html = $this->load->view('controller/viewfile', $data, true);
     $html=$this->input->post('pdfContent');
     pdf_create($html, 'filename');
     /*or
     $data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
     write_file('name', $data);*/
     //if you want to write it to disk and/or send it as an attachment    
}

function getsectionsmallbox($section_id){
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $rtnVal=$this->user_model->getsectionsmallbox($section_id);
   echo json_encode($rtnVal);
}

function getsectiontablewidget($section_id){
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $rtnVal=$this->user_model->getsectiontablewidget($section_id);
   echo json_encode($rtnVal);
}

function getsectionwidget($section_id){
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $rtnVal=$this->user_model->getsectionwidget($section_id);
   echo json_encode($rtnVal);
}

function getfilters($dashboard_id){
   if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $rtnVal=$this->user_model->getfilters($dashboard_id);
   echo json_encode($rtnVal);
}

function checkmaintenance(){
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $maintenance=$this->user_model->checkmaintenance();
    if($maintenance){
        redirect('./home/undermaintenance', 'refresh');
    }
}

function undermaintenance(){
    $pageData['undermaintenance']=true;
    $this->load->view('header', $pageData);
    $this->load->view('undermaintenance');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

function advtable(){
    $this->load->view('advtable');
}

function edittable(){
    if($this->checklogin()==false){ $this->logout();}
    $this->checkmaintenance();
    $pageData=Array();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->view('header', $pageData);
    $this->load->view('edittable');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

function getedittabledata(){
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $tableData=$this->user_model->getedittabledata();
    echo json_encode($tableData);
}

function getedittabledatasave(){
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $tableData=$this->user_model->getedittabledatasave();
    echo json_encode($tableData);
}

function getedittabledataupdate(){
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $tableData=$this->user_model->getedittabledataupdate();
    echo json_encode($tableData);
}

function getedittabledatadelete(){
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $tableData=$this->user_model->getedittabledatadelete();
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
}   }
```

Comment: check your config/route.php or .htaccess file

Comment: You may need to set your routes http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Comment: have you included `/beat/` in your base url in config.php?

Comment: If you are using Codeigniter 3, you need to make sure your controller's filename begins with a capital letter; `Home.php` not `home.php`

Answer (score 0):

try this url please  index.php/beat/home/userhome or
try this please  index.php after your base url and please reroute from route.php that is the proper way

Answer (score 0):

first put this code in .htaccess file on root

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

check Class file name .

set your config file

Answer (score 0):

First: try the default url in CodeIgniter: beat/**index.php**/home/userhome

If it still does not work, try to [routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=route#uri-routing):

Routing: config/routes.php

```
$route['home/userhome'] = 'home/userhome';
```

If it worked, then you can remove **index.php** from url, [read this](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file).

One more thing: I don't know what version you're using. If you're using CodeIgniter 3.0, then you need to change the file name, [read more about Style Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming).